# error npm install -g iron-meteor on windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

Can not install iron-meteor with command:`npm install -g iron-meteor`

**installed**

1. os
   　win 8.1 pro
2. node -v
   　v0.12.2
3. npm -v
   　2.7.4
4. python --version
   　Python 2.7.9
5. I also have Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 in my machine, and later installed Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop.

When I

> run: **npm install -g -iron-meteor**

I got **error** below:

> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable
>   parallel build,please add the "/m" switch.   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(64,5):
>   error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build
>   tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools. Alternatively,
>   you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the
>   Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade
>   Solution...".
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>
> gyp ERR! build error    gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe failed with exit code: 1   gyp ERR!
>   stack at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)   gyp ERR!
>   stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (child_process.js:1074:12)   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600   gyp
>   ERR! command "node"
>   "D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" "--release"   gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers
>   gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3   gyp ERR! not
>   ok   Build failed   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600   npm ERR! argv
>   "D:\nodejs\\node.exe"
>   "D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "iron-meteor"   npm ERR! node v0.12.2   npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4   npm
>   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE   npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: node ./build.js 
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1   npm ERR!   npm ERR! Failed at the
>   fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.   npm ERR! This is most
>   likely a problem with the fibers package,   npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself.   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node ./build.js   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers   npm ERR! There is likely additional
>   logging output above.

And, when

> run: **npm install -g iron-meter --msvs-version=2012** or **npm install -g >    iron-meter --msvs-version=2013**

I got **result**:

> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable
>   parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.   fibers.cc   coroutine.cc
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\xlocale(336): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>   (..\src\fibers.cc)
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   ..\src\fibers.cc(703): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
>   'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   ..\src\fibers.cc(707): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double'
>   to 'size_t', possible loss of data
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   ..\src\fibers.cc(714): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
>   'size_t' to'double', possible loss of data
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   ..\src\coroutine.cc(109): warning C4552: '!' : operator has no effect;
>   expectedoperator with side-effect
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   ..\src\coroutine.cc(185): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from
>   'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\vector(1066): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>   (..\src\coroutine.cc)
>   [C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\vector(1059) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<_Ty::resize(unsigned __int64)' with
>   [_Ty=void *]   ..\src\coroutine.cc(146) : see reference to function
>   template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty::resize(unsigned
>   __int64)' being compiled with [_Ty=void *] coro.c   Creating library C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\Release\fibers.lib
>   and object
>   C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\Release\fibers.exp
>   Generating code   Finished generating code   fibers.vcxproj
>   -C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\build\Release\fibers.node
>   Installed in
>   C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-x64-v8-3.28\fibers.node
>   C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\iron 
>   C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor\bin\iron
>   iron-meteor@1.1.2
>   C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\iron-meteor

├── single-line-log@0.4.1
├── xtend@4.0.0
├── minimist@0.0.8
├── underscore@1.3.3
├── ejs@0.8.5
├── cli-table@0.3.0 (colors@0.6.2)
├── cli-color@0.2.3 (es5-ext@0.9.2, memoizee@0.2.6)
├── shell-source@1.0.1 (concat-stream@1.4.8)
└── fibers@1.0.5

**Can anyone help me?**

Comment: Have you tried installing the Visual Studio 2010 build tools as requested in the first error message?